# Why the guideline - rollback action should appear before its install action in the execution sequence?

Tags: windows-installer

The guideline (infact it is mentioned as a rule) says:

"The rollback custom action should be inserted directly in front of the deferred custom action so that it is added to the rollback script immediately before the deferred custom action is executed. This ensures proper rollback in case the installation is aborted during your custom action" (http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

I have the following execution sequence:

InstallInitialize 
 - InstallFiles
 - MakeConfigChanges
 - RollbackConfigChanges
 - CommitConfigChanges
 - InstallFinalize

In the above sample I have placed the rollback action - RollbackConfigChanges after its corresponding install action. I feel that it will still generate the correct install, rollback and commit script. Correct?

If the correct scripts get generated irrespective of the ordering of actions between InstallInitialize and InstallFinalize then what the above mentioned guideline is about? What is the recommendation (if any) for ordering actions between the InstallInitialize and the InstallFinalize block?

Thanks.

**Update**
When the rollback action appears after its install action then they are not called as they are not written to the rollback script. I tried by modifying the sequence in the msi setup and then executing it. The rollback action was not invoked. Hence the guideline is correct and the sample sequence mentioned above is not correct and will not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See "Rollback Custom Actions" in the MSI SDK. Rollback is managed by a separate generated script, so if the rollback custom action appears after the custom action it rolls back, it won't be part of the script.

Comment: The thing that confuses me is: there is no association between install and its corresponding rollback action. Secondly, when is the rollback script generated? Could u please look at the sample (in question) and tell me whether it will perform correctly or not?

Comment: The association is the order. As you note, the documentation is correct and your proposal won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You want to read:

[Installation Phases and In-Script Execution Options for Custom Actions in Windows Installer](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/isnews/200108/index.htm)

It answers many questions probably some you haven't thought to ask yet.   For the question at hand, it's because there is a script generation phase and a script execution phase.   When the rollback occurs, it takes the end of rollback script and starts walking it backwards in a sense.  If your rollback action is schedule after your deferred then it will never run your rollback action because of this relationship.

Comment: I have got the same link reference mentioned in my question. I was under impression that the rollback script is generated along with install script generation and due to that order should not matter. But, it is getting generated when the install script is under execution and hence order matters.

Answer (score 0):

All depends on your custom action cleanup code. What happens if your action returned error? If it **leaves** data that should be cleaned up, rollback action should come before your CA. Otherwise (smartest case) rollback should be **after** your CA.

If your action tries to copy a file, what happens with file if the action failed?

So, rollback action should delete a file that has been copied in your CA. But your CA failed to copy a file - nothing to delete.

Habit of all installer makers, mr. Rob and MSDN doesn't mean that they do their things well. Mind about the mistake.

They are right when it depends on 'Cancel' user action. If your action completes successfully before it returns, and user clicked 'Cancel' button parallelly with action execution, the action needs to be rolled back. So, if all your CA are synchronous and you disable 'Cancel' button in deferred phase, schedule rollback actions **after** your CAs.

Another alternative - is to check success of your deferred actions in their corresponding rollback actions. Such success should be marked in the end of action.

Comment: Note: you can disable 'Cancel' button while your long-running deferred action executing. Disable it before you start, and enable at function return. Code example here: [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368791(v=vs.85).aspx).